# Responsive slider buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im trying to position some buttons below a slider and I can do so, but the entire site is responsive (botstrap) except for these buttons. So I'm trying to make them so.

I have been trying to work with percents to position them and create fluid heights and widths, but I have had no luck. All I can seem to do is position them on top of one another.

My html looks like this

```
 <div class="col-md-12 sliderBar">
      <img src="assets/img/aboutPage.png" alt="" />
    </div><!--.col-md-12-->
    <div class="col-md-12 sliderNav">
      <div class="container">
        <button> < </button>
        <button>Sponges</button>
        <button>DBM</button>
        <button>Synthetics</button>
        <button> > </button>
      </div><!--.container-->
    </div><!--.col-md-12-->
```

and my css looks like this

```
.sliderNav{
  background-color: #1b1a29;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:3%;
  height:0;
  overflow:hidden;

}

.sliderNav button{
  position:absolute;
  width:20%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Any help would be great! I have a fiddle set up [here](http://jsfiddle.net/7u2RJ/).

Comment: could you add an image of the result you expect? Look to http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified too maybe.

Comment: @BassJobsen I'm really just looking on how to make those buttons responsive. If they start out larger then they should shrink as the screen smaller. It's not really style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this what you want? [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7u2RJ/2/)

the changes i made are position to relative for button, set button width 15%.. let me know if works :)

here is the code i modified:

```
.container button{
  position:relative;
  width:15%;
  height:100%;
}
```

Comment: This works wonderfully, my only issue is I need to make them taller (didn't even think of this until I looked at my comp again) so you think that's possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this (no additional css needed):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="col-md-12 sliderBar">
      <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/41/Blank_Earth_Banner.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive" />
    </div><!--.col-md-12-->

   <div class="col-md-12">    
      <div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
        <a class="btn btn-default"> &lt; </a>
        <a class="btn btn-default">Sponges</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default">DBM</a>
        <a class="btn btn-default">SYNTECHICS</a>  
        <a class="btn btn-default"> &gt; </a>
      </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this doesn't quite work for me because the buttons have to be quite high to start out with and while this does position them it does not make them responsive and grow smaller as the screen gets smaller.

Comment: i don't understand see: http://bootply.com/82473. Do your buttons have to be the same size on different screens?

Comment: bootply does not allow you to se it, but when it is in a jsfiddle or in an actual website the buttons do not shrink. This also does no alow me to enlarge them the way I need them to be.

Comment: i don't know why the bootply don't work, chech the example on http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-justified this buttons resize (and justify) with your screen (but the totaal size will be 100% of the viewport)